# How to JSON encode multiple rows from SQL statement using PHP

Tags: php, ios, mysql, json

I'm in the process of building an iOS app that uses a webservice for data. The webservice consists of PHP, MySQL database.

I've successfully managed to JSON encode the data returned, but the code I am using only seems to encode 1 row.

I wanted to get some advice on how to encode multiple rows?

Thanks.

```
<?php
$username = "root";
$password = "*******";
$hostname = "localhost";
$dbh = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password)
or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");

//print "Connected to MySQL<br>";

$selected = mysql_select_db("newtest",$dbh)
or die("Could not select first_test");

$query = "SELECT * FROM MyGuests ";
$result=mysql_query($query);

echo json_encode(mysql_fetch_assoc($result));

?>
```

Comment: You are only fetching one row of the result set.  You need to fetch them all.

Comment: Please, [don't use `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php), They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://us1.php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://us1.php.net/mysqli).

Comment: Thanks for this, back to the drawing board for me!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to encode json with multiple rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51657380/how-to-encode-json-with-multiple-rows)

Answer (score 2):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM MyGuests ";
$result=mysql_query($query);
$rows = array();
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $rows[] = $r;
}
print_r json_encode($rows);
```

Comment: You're mixing `mysql_` and `mysqli_` functions. That will not work.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. I've implemented this change, and previously when accessing the URL for this query on a browser it displayed the single row as JSON, but not the page shows blank. Have I done something wrong or is this expected? Sorry for the noob questions!