# How to encode json with multiple rows?

Tags: php, json

Before I begin, I have looked through other examples and Q&A's on multiple platforms but none of them seem to solve my problem. I am trying to return multiple rows from MySQL via a json. However, I have been unable to. The code below shows my attempt.

I get my responses via Postman. The first `while` returns only the last entry in the database, and the `do-while` returns all entries but doesn't encode the json properly, as the json outputs `syntax error` but the html part shows all entries.

```
<?php
    $dashboard_content_token = $_REQUEST["dashboard_content_token"];
    $token = "g4";

    require(cc_scripts/connect.php);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `dashboard_content`";
    $check = strcmp("$token", "$dashboard_content_token");
    $statement = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    if (check) {
        $rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($statement);
        if (!$rows) {
            echo "No results!";
        } else {
              while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($statement)) {
                $news_id = $rows['news_id'];
                $image_url = $rows['image_url'];
                $news_title = $rows['news_title'];
                $news_description = $rows['news_description'];
                $news_article = $rows['news_article'];

                $result['dashboard content: '][] = array('news_id' => $news_id, 'image_url' => $image_url, 'news_title' => $news_title, 'news_description' => $news_description, 'news_article' => $news_article); 

                echo json_encode($result);
        }
        // do {
                // $news_id = $rows['news_id'];
                // $image_url = $rows['image_url'];
                // $news_title = $rows['news_title'];
                // $news_description = $rows['news_description'];
                // $news_article = $rows['news_article'];

                // $result['dashboard content: '][] = array('news_id' => $news_id, 'image_url' => $image_url, 'news_title' => $news_title, 'news_description' => $news_description, 'news_article' => $news_article); 

                // echo json_encode($result);
        //     } while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($statement));


        mysqli_free_result($statement);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: I think you want to use a `do-while` here. Otherwise the first result is skipped.  Do you only have two results in the database?

Comment: You may be getting the syntax error because you are echoing `json_encode()` multiple times.  What if you add all of your database entries to the `$result` array and do one `echo json_encode($result);` after your `do-while` loop?

Comment: For now yes, I only have two. I will still flood my database with more stuff later on. The `do-while` doesn't encode the json properly.

Comment: @joeljoeljoel Your suggestion worked beautifully, would like to post an answer and an explanation, in case of other people. Also, so I can mark it and you'll get some reputation.

Comment: @joeljoeljoel It just hit me but how did you know I only have 2 entries in my database?

Comment: It was a couple things.  First, in your code example the first db result was being skipped because you call mysqli_fetch_assoc() twice before you begin to json_encode the data. Once after the first if() statement and then again to start your while() loop.  Second, echoing json_encode() multiple times will result in invalid JSON.  Since the while loop worked but only returned the last result made me think there were only 2 entries in the database. Hope this helps

Comment: Hmm... this was a really good guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. You'll want to use the `do...while` statement otherwise the first result is skipped.

```
<?php
    $dashboard_content_token = $_REQUEST["dashboard_content_token"];
    $token = "g4";

    require(cc_scripts/connect.php);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `dashboard_content`";
    $check = strcmp("$token", "$dashboard_content_token");
    $statement = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    if (check) {
        $rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($statement);
        if (!$rows) {
            echo "No results!";
        } else {

          do {
             $news_id = $rows['news_id'];
             $image_url = $rows['image_url'];
             $news_title = $rows['news_title'];
             $news_description = $rows['news_description'];
             $news_article = $rows['news_article'];

               $result['dashboard content: '][] = array('news_id' => $news_id, 'image_url' => $image_url, 'news_title' => $news_title, 'news_description' => $news_description, 'news_article' => $news_article); 


          } while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($statement));

        mysqli_free_result($statement);
        echo json_encode($result);
    }
}
?>
```

The key is to put all of you results into an array and then just do one `json_encode()`.  When you call `json_encode()` multiple times, your API will return invalid json.

Comment: Can you do the same thing but with prepared statements?

Answer (score 1):

In your while loop,

```
$result['dashboard content: '] = array('news_id' => $news_id, 'image_url' => $image_url, 'news_title' => $news_title, 'news_description' => $news_description, 'news_article' => $news_article);
```

just over-writes the same "dashboard content" entry in the $result array every time you run the loop. This is why you only see the last entry.

Doing json_encode() within the loop makes no sense as well, because you'll just output multiple, disconnected individual JSON objects, which are not part of an array or coherent structure. This doesn't make for a valid JSON response.

It's not abundantly clear exactly what output structure you're hoping for, but this might give you either a solution, or at least a shove in the right direction:

```
$statement = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$result = array("dashboard_content" => array()); //create an associative array with a property called "dashboard_content", which is an array. (json_encode will convert an associative array to a JSON object)

if (check) {
    $rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($statement);
    if (!$rows) {
        echo "No results!";
    } else {
          while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($statement)) {
            $news_id = $rows['news_id'];
            $image_url = $rows['image_url'];
            $news_title = $rows['news_title'];
            $news_description = $rows['news_description'];
            $news_article = $rows['news_article'];

            //append the current data to a new entry in the "dashboard_content" array
            $result["dashboard_content"][] = array('news_id' => $news_id, 'image_url' => $image_url, 'news_title' => $news_title, 'news_description' => $news_description, 'news_article' => $news_article); 
        }
    }

    //now, output the whole completed result to one single, coherent, valid JSON array.
    echo json_encode($result);
```

You should end up with some JSON like this:

```
{
  "dashboard_content": [
    {
      "news_id": 1,
      "image_url": "abc",
      "news_title": "xyz",
      //...etc
    },
    {
      "news_id": 2,
      "image_url": "def",
      "news_title": "pqr",
      //...etc
    },
    //...etc
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, you were indeed correct. But someone else had already solved my problem in the comments and I was waiting for him to post a proper answer so that I could accept it.